# asp.net 2.0 asp:FIleUpload control saving uploaded files to a different server

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I'm trying to use an asp:FileUpload Control to allow users to upload files (.doc, .gif, .xls, .jpg) to a server that is outside of our DMZ and not the Web Server. We want to have the ability to look at these files for viruses, structure, etc prior to saving them into another directory that would allow access to outside users. From what I have read about this control is that it will allow for files to be uploaded to the web server. Can this control be used to upload files to a server other than the web server? If it can be done where should I look for this type of functionality or how do I force it to go to https:\servername\folder name (Where server name is not the web server)? Would I have to read the file then write it to the other server?

Thanks,
Erin

Answer (score 1):

FileUoload control can only upload data to the web server. If you need to save file to a different server, you need handle the POST request, read data from the Fileupload control and save them to your UNC share.

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, using the fileupload control you actually upload contents to webserver which inturn gets rendered to your client (page) when requested; I don't think you can upload files to different server other than webserver; that shouldn't happen as well. Take a look at the below URL for fileupload if you want

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx

http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/uploading-files-cs

Thanks.

Comment: @Artyom and @Rahul I figured out how to actually do this. Essentially using the same line of code that was contained in my initial question: ("\\servername\foldername" & FileUpLoad1.FileName). My issue was I was missing the PostedFile property in my SaveAs. It should look like this to get it to work properly: FileUpLoad1.PostedFile.SaveAs("\\servername\foldername" & FileUpLoad1.FileName). Once I added this property to my code it allowed me to upload the files. The folder has security permissions set to allow me to write to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your web server setting and permission granted to the application. If it is DMZ then I would assume that a very minimal permission is granted to the application. In such scenario the application will not be able to access any resource other than webserver unless an explicit permission is granted to the account running application to access the network resource (which is not recommended). However, if the nework server you are trying to save the file has ftp enabled, then you could write the bytes streamed in file upload control to the network server with authenticated ftp account that has necessary permission.

You may use the below function:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO

    Public Function Upload(ByVal FileByte() As Byte, ByVal FileName As String, ByVal ftpUserID As String, ByVal ftpPassword As String, ByVal ftpURL As String) As Boolean

        Dim retValue As Boolean = False

        Try
            Dim ftpFullPath As String = ftpURL + "/" + FileName
            Dim ftp As FtpWebRequest = FtpWebRequest.Create(New Uri(ftpFullPath))
            ftp.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword)
            ftp.KeepAlive = True
            ftp.UseBinary = True
            ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
            Dim ftpStream As Stream = ftp.GetRequestStream()
            ftpStream.Write(FileByte, 0, FileByte.Length)
            ftpStream.Close()
            ftpStream.Dispose()
            retValue = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
        Return retValue
    End Function
```

Function Call:

```
Upload(FileUploadControl.FileBytes, "filename.ext" "user", "password", "ftppath")
```